# deploy artifact's without compile using mvn and Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml, artifactory

I have a multi-model project (maven project) and I'm using Jenkins pipeline to build and deploy the artifact. I want to  compile all the child projects, and only if the compilation was seceded, I want to deploy the artifacts. How can I deploy the artifacts without compile them again? I tried to use:

```
mvn jar:jar deploy:deploy
```

But I also have zip and war files and it didn't deploy them. Also:

```
mvn zip:zip deploy:deploy
```

didn't work.

Comment: Just use simply `mvn clean deploy`...easy works ...

Comment: But then my project is compile twice and the build is take to long..

Comment: If so you have an issue in your build...compiling is only done once in the life cycle ...so there is something wrong in your build configuration. Calling the goals manually is simply wrong....

Comment: What I mean is that between the install and the deploy I have sonarQube, so I want that is: If build pass the sonar analysis successfully, it will deploy the artifacts without compile.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit late but I had the same issue and got the same error and the following command works for my use case

```
mvn clean install
mvn deploy -Dmaven.install.skip=true -DskipTests
```